# Retrofit: How to make XML request and get back JSON response

Tags: android, json, xml, xmlhttprequest, retrofit2

how could I make a simple text/xml POST request and get JSON back using retrofit 2 !!!???
**note 1**:i already know how to make JSON GET/POST request and get back JSON as a response.
**note 2**: I have an endpoint in which the request is in XML SOAP format and the response is in JSON format. for clarification I'll post sample request response here:

**XML Sample Request:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <username>0370079361</username>
      <password>4321</password>
    </Login>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**JSON Sample Response:**

```
{
    "UserID": 2081,
    "FailureText": null,
    "UserValidPasswordCode": 2081,
    "UserPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode": true
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found the answer myself, actually it was SUPER EASY.

APIService Class:(**RequestBody** is the key here)

```
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface RetrofitAPIService {
//    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/webservice.asmx?op=Login")
    Call<RetrofitResponseBody> login(@Body RequestBody body);
}
```

**note:** the key for the following code is this line:

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/xml"), requestBodyText);
```

MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText userName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
        EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);

        RetrofitAPIService mAPIService = RetrofitAPIUtils.getRetrofitAPIService();

        String requestBodyText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n" +
                "  <soap12:Body>\n" +
                "    <Login xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n" +
                "      <username>" + userName.getText() + "</username>\n" +
                "      <password>" + password.getText() + "</password>\n" +
                "    </Login>\n" +
                "  </soap12:Body>\n" +
                "</soap12:Envelope>";
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/xml"), requestBodyText);
        Call<RetrofitResponseBody> response = mAPIService.login(requestBody);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<RetrofitResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RetrofitResponseBody> call, Response<RetrofitResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    Log.d("JavadR:",
                            response.body().getUserID().toString() +
                                    " - " +
                                    response.body().getFailureText()
                    );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RetrofitResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
```

the **RetrofitResponseBody** is not of too much importance but for consistency and convenience I'll post it here:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RetrofitResponseBody {

    @SerializedName("UserID")
    @Expose
    private Integer userID;
    @SerializedName("FailureText")
    @Expose
    private Object failureText;
    @SerializedName("UserValidPasswordCode")
    @Expose
    private Integer userValidPasswordCode;
    @SerializedName("UserPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode")
    @Expose
    private Boolean userPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode;

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public Object getFailureText() {
        return failureText;
    }

    public void setFailureText(Object failureText) {
        this.failureText = failureText;
    }

    public Integer getUserValidPasswordCode() {
        return userValidPasswordCode;
    }

    public void setUserValidPasswordCode(Integer userValidPasswordCode) {
        this.userValidPasswordCode = userValidPasswordCode;
    }

    public Boolean getUserPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode() {
        return userPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode;
    }

    public void setUserPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode(Boolean userPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode) {
        this.userPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode = userPatientIsActiveWithNationalIDCode;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Javed can you post answer if response is also in xml format same as request xml? i have getting issue with RetrofitResponseBody POJO class.   it showing "org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Parameter 'soap:Body' does not have a match in class com.kgk.kis.ui.auth.LoginResponse"