# Post request by Retrofit with Request HTTP code below

Tags: java, android, kotlin, httprequest, retrofit2

I have request HTTP below. Now, I want to use retrofit to post request to get response

```
POST /sony/ircc HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.0.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1#X_SendIRCC"
X-Auth-PSK: 1234
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 313

<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:X_SendIRCC xmlns:u="urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1">
            <IRCCCode>AAAAAQAAAAEAAAB1Aw==</IRCCCode>
        </u:X_SendIRCC>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Please show me steps to POST request and GET response. Please comment if you need information more from me.

Comment: I find way to resolve this problem in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699776/retrofit-how-to-make-xml-request-and-get-back-json-response

Answer (score 0):

I find way to resolve this problem in here: [Retrofit: How to make XML request and get back JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699776/retrofit-how-to-make-xml-request-and-get-back-json-response)

Step 1: APIClient.kt

```
class APIClient private constructor() {
    private val apiService: ApiServices

    init {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
                override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                    val request: Request = chain.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("X-Auth-PSK", SonyApiEndpoints.SONY_PRE_SHARED_KEY)
                        .build()
                    return chain.proceed(request)
                }
            })
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .build()
        val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://[IP]/sony")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
        apiService = retrofit.create(ApiServices::class.java)
    }

    fun getApiService(): ApiServices{
        return apiService
    }

    companion object {
        var instance: APIClient? = null
            get() {
                if (field == null) {
                    field = APIClient()
                }
                return field
            }
            private set
    }
}
```

Step 2:ApiServices.kt

```
  @POST("/ircc)
  fun setRemoteController(@Body request: RequestBody)
```

Step 3: Implement

```
 fun setRemoteController(IRCCCode: String) {
        val requestBodyText = "<s:Envelope\n" +
                "    xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\n" +
                "    s:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">\n" +
                "    <s:Body>\n" +
                "        <u:X_SendIRCC xmlns:u=\"urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1\">\n" +
                "            <IRCCCode>${IRCCCode}</IRCCCode>\n" +
                "        </u:X_SendIRCC>\n" +
                "    </s:Body>\n" +
                "</s:Envelope>"
        val requestBody = requestBodyText.toRequestBody("text/xml".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        APIClient.instance?.getApiService()?.setRemoteController(requestBody)
    }
```

Comment: I find way to resolve this problem in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699776/retrofit-how-to-make-xml-request-and-get-back-json-response